# Problem with integration limits using spherical substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, contour-integration

Good night, i have a problem with this integral, please help me with the integration limits.

\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}^{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^{2}-y^{2}}}^{\sqrt{1-x^{2}-y^{2}}}\left(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\right)^{3/2}dzdydx    &=  \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{-\cos\alpha}^{\cos\alpha} (r^{5} sen\alpha) {\rm d}r {\rm d}\alpha {\rm d}\beta \\
&= 1/3\,\int_{0}^{2\,\pi }\!\int_{0}^{\pi }\! \left( \sin x \cos x \right) ^{6}\,{\rm d}
x\,{\rm d}y \\
&= \frac{4\pi}{21} \\
\end{align}

But the answer is $\frac{2\pi}{3}$, please help me.

Comment: The limit on the radial variable are from $0$ to $1$.  What is $\alpha$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transforming to spherical coordinates, we find that

$$\begin{align}
\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}^{\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^{2}-y^{2}}}^{\sqrt{1-x^{2}-y^{2}}}\left(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}\right)^{3/2}dzdydx
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi\int_0^1 r^5\,dr\sin(\theta)\,d\theta\,d\phi\\\\&=(2\pi)(2)\left(\frac16\right)\\\\
&=\frac{2\pi}{3}\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: Thanks man but i have a question, how you can find the radial $0<r<1$? and $\alpha=\phi$

Comment: The integration region is a unit sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2=1$.

Comment: And you're welcome.  My pleasure.  -Mark